# facebook registration plugin - show on click only?

Tags: facebook, registration

I am trying to implement the FB registration plugin on my site but it is active/opened by default. is there a way to have it open only when a user clicks on the Register/Login button instead?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a hidden div and then show the div when you want to with javascript

Comment: Thank you. I did that after not being able to figure it out thinking maybe I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the page where you want Register button to be displayed:

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="http://yoursite.com/facebookregistration" />
```

facebookregistration page should have the registration form:

```
<fb:registration 
  fields="[
 {'name':'name'},
 {'name':'email'},
 {'name':'gender'},
 {'name':'birthday'}
]" 
</fb:registration>
```

For more information refer to [Facebook Developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)